Expecting ad hominem criticism in a thesis defense: How to prepare well for this?
To be short, I have a bad relationship with my advisor. He told me my research ideas are wrong and that he was not convinced of them without giving reasons. I proceeded against his opinion and presented the work at a highly selective conference in the field and was encouraged to submit a publication by the experts there. In addition, he was neglecting me all along but I had support from other professors from outside universities. So I did very briefly thank him in the acknowledgement section and generously thanked those who did the support. He lately disparaged a colleague's work in her public defense, after not giving her any guidance or support nor comments on her drafts.
I feel it coming, that he is going to try to make my public defense hell, and I am expecting lots of adhominem criticism. What are some tips that you suggest to stand mentally strong in such a situation, and keep it professional? For example, how did you handle a destructive/unfair criticism in a presentation?
Note: My examiners are all male friends with my advisors.
Update: I believe there are 2 kinds of criticism: constructive and destructive. Constructive, that which is based on truth and reason and delivered in such a way to benefit the listener. There are 2 kinds of destructive criticism that which is based on truth but, delivered in such a way to hurt the listener and undermine their wellbeing and the other is based on falsehood/claims and delivered with ill intentions to undermine the listener's wellbeing, hurt their reputation .. etc. Ad hominem criticism is one form of the latter.
I am preparing for the bad scenarios, as well as the good. I have valid reasons to expect such type of destructive criticism. I want to defend myself and reputation in a rational ptofessional way, but questioning when to say "thanks for your opinion" and when to rationally refute it. Like if someone says "this is a trivial idea" without proof, I'd not let that pass and tell him "thanks for your opinion" and I'd ask for a proof for this claim and I'd support the case "that it is not a trivial idea" based on truth, and others approval who are experts.
The professors who helped are from US universities, they cannot be present. However, I mention their names in the ack., and those who thought highly of my work and they are well-known in the field.
I am not in Europe nor the US.
Addressing the comments asking about why I stayed with an unsupportive advisor: Yes. It is a mistake on my part, I should have left. However, other available options at the time seemed equal, and  I am generally an independent student and didn't mind the independence granted to me in effect to his behaviour, and thought that if I did a really  good job, I could change his mind. Anyway, I learned through the experience and gained new connections from respected universities who would open doors for me in the future. I know that I did a mistake but it is not as bad as that of a person who is 3x my age, with tenure and more life experiences. Also I decided to not dwell on past mistakes, and tortue myself for them. I just want to get out with minimal losses.

Please can you mention what country you are in? Practices around defences etc vary a lot across the world.

"Destructive/unfair criticism" is different from "ad hominem". Do you really expect your advisor to attack your person/character rather than the content of the work? Or do you expect unfairly harsh criticism on the content?

Both.  I regard ad hominem criticism as one form of destructive criticism. I expect anything that is delivered with ill intentions to hurt my reputation and satisfy his ego ..

My feeling is that you make the common mistake of focusing a lot on your advisor's intention and not enough on what he can and will actually do. Frankly it doesn't matter if your advisor poses a critical challenge because he wants to test you, because he wants to preserve the integrity of science, or because he hates you and wants to sink your defence. In any case you need to have a convincing argument to his challenge.

Who is chairing your defence?

Is the defense open to visitors or closed? You seem to indicate public.

I think the truly fundamental question is, why are you working with an advisor who does not support you or your research at all?  There are valid answers to that question, but knowing your answer will probably help people give you better advice.

The correct reply is well documented.

Practice with a friend. Have them pretend to be the advisor and say the specific phrases that you expect can make you lose your composture, and practice responding to those.

As Tom van der Zanden says "ad hominin" means an attack on you personally rather than your work. It would be extremely surprising if your advisor did that, because it would be very unprofessional behaviour and would probably get your advisor fired. Harsh or unfair criticism is different.

OP is in precisely the right mindset. They have identified the problem and approach it rationally. There are various techniques listed in below answers, but the part they have to prepare the most is how to actually implement them under psychological pressure.

Just don't get angry or emotional as this will make things worse, calmly respond to each question even if you think it is deliberately unfair.  Famous case was Weinberg did not get on with Feynman as Feynman was apparently jealous of Weinberg's rise to fame and would aggressively attack all his arguments during Weinberg's talks, even if his arguments were watertight.  Just one of those things.  It's fine not to like your advisor very much, but keep all your responses calm and professional.

Prepare to be as objective as possible. Prepare to not respond emotionally to unfair criticism. You cannot stop your advisor from making it clear that they dislike your work, but you can be professional about it. Focus on your work – if it is sound and interesting, the examiners will have a hard time bringing up reasonable criticism without seeming nit-picky. Likely, they have a reputation to lose.
I have been in the audience of a thesis defense which acted out similar to the scenario you are fearing. The candidate succeeded by agreeing with reasonable criticism, explaining the soundness of their approach, and countering unreasonable objections.

How does this answer address the issue of ad-hominem attacks on the person?

This reminds me of how Kamala Harris was advised to deal with Trump in their debate: don't stoop to his level.

@DanielR.Collins if someone is stupid enough to make such an attack in a thesis defence, you can simply say "what has that got to do with the thesis?"

@cmw Ideally both should be about the issues. Dealing with someone who strays from this can be similar.

@cmw That's what I meant by "ideally". A thesis defense should be about the technical material, not the biases of the professors.

@OrangeDog OP is not the moderator, and OP's superior. "What has that got to do with the thesis" is a formulation to use with an equal, as it puts the other person on the spot. Better something like: "Could you please clarify the connection of this argument to what I said?" or "I fail to see the connection, could you please clarify?" Generally, requests for clarification are less confrontational and offer the option to move back to rational discussion (even if it's likely that the prof may not want to do it, but then the ball is in their court)

At least where I am from, the thesis advisor has a very strong influence on whether a student graduates. That's one of their primary roles: to determine that a student under their supervision has satisfactorily completed an apprenticeship with them and is ready to be a more independent researcher.
That said, the role is not entirely theirs, and that's why there is a thesis committee. Usually, though, that committee of examiners is there to bring more rigor to the table, not to overrule the advisor (though it may happen in special cases). While you describe support from "professors from outside universities" I do not get the sense that these outside supporters are the same people as the male friends of your advisor on your committee.
If your advisor plans to come to your defense with ad hominem criticism, I think refuting their specific criticisms are far less important than the demonstration by this activity that they do not support your defense. If they plan to vote against your passing, that's all that matters, and it's extremely unlikely that you will be able to convince them in the moment if you have not convinced them until now, no matter how you prepare.
I would not describe stating that your "research ideas are wrong and that he was not convinced of them" is an ad hominem. Ad hominem criticisms are those that target some off-topic trait or motivation. In the context of research, however, the burden is on the person bringing the ideas and convincing their audience. "I am not convinced" is not ad hominem. Be prepared to convincingly demonstrate your research. Be aware of the possible (academic) criticisms of your work and its weaknesses and be ready to respond to those.

This is a great answer. Many students can lose focus that rigorous questioning of science is not an ad hominem. It can feel like that in the moment, but it is not. To the OP, unfortunately they set up a terrible situation by getting an advisor, and then completely disregarding their advice. It really doesn't matter who is right or wrong, but one can clearly see that it sets up a highly adversarial situation that is unproductive for both the advisor and advisee.

@R1NaNo Yes, and I believe I have commented similarly on previous questions by OP: they had a disagreement with their advisor and chose to go out entirely on their own. If the relationship was irreparable, OP should have found another advisor to guide them. Because they didn't, now they're in a situation where the person who should be most championing their student's success at a defense seems likely to be the one most opposed. Bad situation.

While it's not the literal definition of "ad hominem", if the advisor doesn't provide constructive criticism it's easy to assume that they're just hiding their disapproval of the student in seemingly academic language. The OP's mention of another student suggests that the professor may have an issue with female advisees.

@Barmar That may be, but there is no way to state that claim during a defense that will improve ones chances. If the advisor is so biased that they can't supervise OP, OP needed to leave sooner, regardless of which exact characteristics the advisor is unable to deal with.

I'm not suggesting that they should say anything about it during the defense.

Agree with this answer (+1).  I think that technically the OP is not referring to ad hominem but rather to criticisms that baldly assert a negative evaluation of the work without giving reasons.  The anticipated form of criticism here is bald assertion, so OP should prepare to deal with statements of this kind.

@Barmar The proper place to make that accusation is to the university's diversity and inclusion department.

It's not about convincing the advisor. It's about convincing the committee. I generally liked the response, but with this point missing, it's not enough to upvote it, as I think this is critical information.

@CaptainEmacs The point is missing because I mostly disagree with it. Did you read the second paragraph?

@BryanKrause I read it. Ok, if you explicitly disagree with the argument, of course, it's an intentional omission, and you can ignore my comment. I just thought it might help. To be honest, we know too little about the specific power dynamics in that institute. Maybe the supervisor is just about "tough love", maybe they are actually sabotaging OP. It is not unheard of that a student is being treated like an outsider and with maximum scepticism, only to, at the end of the process, to be invited to take up the next position in the career. Though, I would advise against that.

@CaptainEmacs It sounds like OP's advisor was sufficiently critical that OP decided not to work with them anymore, so I think it's a bit different than just "tough love".

@BryanKrause Well, I know of people that decided not to work with some supervisor after finishing their project, and the supervisor did not get why. I saw supervisors strongly berate students (for what turned out to be a misunderstanding) and then not understanding why the student left them. So, while I would always recommend to a student leaving that situation as fast as they can, the supervisor may not realized that they have done bad rather than good. This is absolutely not an excuse for the supervisor, to be unmistakably clear.

@CaptainEmacs Sure, but in any case, it sounds like this student is taking to their defense a dissertation that has not been contributed to by their advisor. They haven't gotten feedback on criticisms the advisor has since the very very beginning of the project, because they chose to go it alone the whole way. While it may be possible for a committee to override or pressure an overly picky advisor or someone who is misguidedly trying to hold onto a student as good labor, I don't think it's as likely that they'll agree that it's okay to just skip all supervision and still graduate.

@BryanKrause Yes, the question is who is at fault here. We know too little about the situation to understand whether the student did not get helpful advice or, rather, was, as they say in German, "beratungsresistent". This wonderful German word is untranslatable in all its connotations, but means more or less "immune/resistant to advice/councel". It seems that you suspect this may be the case?

@CaptainEmacs For deciding whether what happens next is fair or not, fault might matter, but as far as deciding what happens at the defense I don't think it matters much either way who is at fault. I do think that OP's decision to stick with this advisor that they do not have any mutual trust with has made it very likely that they will fail the defense. That doesn't make the original "criticism" their fault.

@BryanKrause My comment was about how to address OP's original question: "How to prepare for ad hominem", nothing more, nothing less. I thought it would enhance your response to make the point to address the committee, but you do not believe so and thus do not add this suggestion - this is your response, and you decide what goes in or not. Whether or not it is OP's mistake either in content or in meta-level was not what my suggestion was driven by; it was indifferent to that. In any case, thanks for the discussion!

If the defense is public then I'd suggest that you have as many supporters of your work as you can present, even if they can't vote. You said you got help from other professors. It would be good and advisable if some of them could be present. I would invite all of those people as well as some students that you trust.
For preparation, you should focus on the work and being able to answer any and all relevant questions about the work, including on any shortcomings. But you should forget about trying to prepare for unwarranted attacks.
In my view, if a professor, especially an advisor, attacks a student in public it reflect badly and only on themself. There should be no place for that in academia. You may need to simply be silent in some situations or respond with "thank you for your views".
Some questions about "shortcomings" are actually an opportunity to speak of future work. But be prepared for questions about methodology as well as results and impact. Don't go beyond what you can demonstrate as true.

I think that's totally right, particularly "You may need to simply be silent in some situations or respond with "thank you for your views". There's no need to win the verbal sparring battle here; simply letting the advisor's vitriol flow over like water is the best way to go. OP: be cautious that the voting here is going to biased in favor of answers that "put your advisor in their place".

@JohnMadden: I expect that prediction will be incorrect.

If they can't be present, you can try to have them join virtually

+10 important point! Make sure you have as many supporters or neutrals present as possible! It makes it harder (though not impossible) for the thesis advisor to act against OP.

If he asks a question, answer whatever question was asked.
If a comment does not contain a question: Nod as politely as possible with eye contact and say "Thank you" as honestly as you can.
If someone asks, say you are glad to hear and grow from criticism. Say it honestly.
Practice that until it comes out as honest. It's very hard to work against that with ad hominem attacks.

What if he makes a statement that's clearly false — should OP try to correct it, or just let it stand?  What about a statement that's misleading, or that contains false assumptions or implications?

@gidds I've never been to a thesis defense, but I thought they basically grill the candidate on their subject matter, not make statements of their own.

@gidds same concept: "The yellow sky proves that the lizards have taken over, that contradicts your main finding that humans are in control." "Thank you for your valuable opinion. My thesis is based on the assumption that the sky is not yellow. Based on that assumption, my findings hold." "But your assumption is wrong." "Thank you."

@DonQuiKong Look out of the window, point out and say "the sky is actually blue". Or else, show the data that state the opposite. If it is an assumption only (i.e. not data-based), then state that it would be interesting to investigate the other assumption and its consequences, but in this work you focused on "the sky is blue" only. "yellow sky" will be investigated in the future.

@CaptainEmacs don't argue with people that pull you down to their level and win on that level by experience.

@DonQuiKong It's a nice saying, but I think the situation does not apply. The OP needs not to beat the prof, it needs to beat the committee. Also, sometimes, you cannot choose the game you are playing. And when mud is thrown, better know how to make pottery out of it.

In additional to the other helpful comments, some practical advice to get through this:

Try stacking the place with people who like you and cheer for you. If the audience is sufficiently positive towards, any of his criticisms will come across as misplaced to any other committee member

Stay calm. Do not get emotional or vindictive under any circumstances at all.

Keep to the protocol and stick to it.

Be intellectually ready to answer or deflect any criticism. This requires intellectual ability and some rhetorical jinjitsu, of course, but I assume at this stage you have got what it takes for that.



Relax a bit, without the consent of your advisor you will never see a defense. That means he thinks you are at a level to graduate. Also, the defense committee does not judge the thesis and the student, they also, internally, judge the advisor. Allowing you to present, he is also staking his reputation. Thus, I don't believe he will attack too harshly. Probably he will be snarky but don't compare his actions against someone else's student, he must be at your side. Remember your failure is his failure to guide you.
Let me finish with this: I am more afraid of my student's defenses than my own PhD defense back then. I make sure they are ready before allowing them to present.

Though this response is kindly intended, note that, in the UK, the student does not need the advisor's permission to request a defense. They can override the supervisor.

What Captain Emacs notes is also true elsewhere. Here in Scandinavia, for instance, the student hands in their thesis to the school. The advisor then submits a statement on whether the student has completed their programme satisfactorily, and if not, the student has the chance to reply. Based on this, the school decides whether to accept the thesis and (if they accept it) sets the date and time for the defence (based on student and advisor availability, of course). Beyond submitting the statement, the advisor has absolutely no influence over any part of this process.

Depending on the country (and I believe this applies to most), an advisor is not supposed to argue with or question you during your thesis defense. The reason is simple: as your thesis advisor, they should have raised these questions before the defense. This is at least the practice in public defenses in France. During the defense, a PhD advisor is usually expected to briefly discuss the candidate’s career path (and sometimes share anecdotes).
If this is not the case for you, it’s important to remain calm and respond with objective arguments. Even if they appear hostile, you’ll be in a better position if you avoid engaging in their tactics. Since it’s a public defense, there will likely be other colleagues in the room. If you remain composed and present your scientific arguments clearly, any hostility is likely to come across as "ridiculous" to the audience.
